# How can I find out what distribution of Python I'm using?

Tags: python

I'm not just looking for the version but specifically the distribution, i.e. whether it's Anaconda, Python(x,y), etc.

Comment: Did either of these answers help? If so, make sure to mark one as correct!

Comment: From my comment below, they work on my computer with an Anaconda distribution, but not for two others I'm working with. On one I get "Python 2.6.6" with nothing else and on the other, I get: unknown error: -- -e -r -s...

Comment: I've since removed whatever distributions I had at the time and installed Anaconda, so it's a moot point now (at least for me)

Comment: So the one that just says Python 2.6.6 was probably because you had a native Python distribution, not Anaconda. For the error I'm guessing either Python wasn't installed or was not in your path. Sounds like you got it now though so good!

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (or command line on Windows) and type `python --version` or `python -V` (capital "V" for the second one). For instance, on my Windows machine this returns:

> Python 3.4.4 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

Unless I'm in my Python 2.7 virtual env, in which case it returns:

> Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

`which python` tells you where the binary is located, but often does not give you much of an idea about which version it is (although if it's in an `anaconda` folder, you know it's anaconda, and that sort of thing).

Comment: This works for my computer with an Anaconda distribution, but not for two others I'm working with. On one I get "Python 2.6.6" with nothing else and on the other I get: unknown error: -- -e -r -s...

Comment: You can also try `python -V`. That's a capital letter "V".

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions:

1. Open a terminal, type `python`, and see what it says in the preamble.
2. In linux, type `which python`
3. On windows, type `where python`